# iOS: move table cell to another section

Tags: ios, tableview

I have a `UITableView` with some sections and rows.

I want to move one row from one section to another section, when I call a function (so not my fingers and I do not want use edit mode of `UITableView`).

How can I do this?

If I recreate a datasource and reload table, it's ok, but it not use animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITableView` offers you methods for this:

call `beginUpdates`, update your datasource, call [moveRowAtIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/moveRowAtIndexPath%3atoIndexPath%3a) and finally call `endUpdates` on `UITableView`

```
[tableView beginUpdates];

// update your datasource
// ... 

// fill in your indexpath of old and new position
[tableView moveRowAtIndexPath: ... toIndexPath: ...];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

EDIT: moveRowAtIndexPath is only for iOS 5+
so you would rather use this:

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: ... withRowAnimation:...];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: ... withRowAnimation:...];
```

Comment: I have tried, and it works within one section. When I try to move from second section to first section, I've got class error: "Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section ... etc".

When I updated my data in tableview datasource, reload the source array (not tableview, only the data!) and after then use your tip.

Where should I use this animation? Before reloading data or after or where?:)

Comment: if you do an animtated tableview update (with begin and endUpdate), you need to pay attention, that you update your data source accordingly (in between begin and endUpdates). such that if you move an item from section 1 to section 2. the datasource must return that the section 1 has one less item and section 2 has one more item. (if that doesn't help you: fell free to post some of your code)